# Brightcove QR Code

Tags: qr-code, brightcove

With Brightcove, what is best practice for playing a single video via a QR code.  The 'short URL' looks awful on a mobile device (mostly white space with a tiny little player the corner).

I've found that the HLS stream works rather seamlessly but I'm be concerned about compatibility with Androids (Brightcove sample video):
http://c.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/master.m3u8?videoId=1520880903001

I'm not as concerned with metrics, just playing the video in the best possible quality in a native mobile environment from a QR code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say build a responsive player within a blank page or template (http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/responsive-sizing-video-players) and direct people there.

That way, you still get the metrics and have a player that will adjust to whatever screen size the user is viewing from.